# error while running the 'node index.js' command for metaplex config.js

Tags: node.js, metaplex

I am at the stage where I have organized my layers and indicated how many nfts I want to generate from each layer configuration. I tried running the command "node index.js" but got the error in the image attached.

Comment: You didn't attach any error, but when you do, please attach it as formatted text, not as an image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're trying to run generate_art_configurations, which has been deprecated. The most used alternative is hashlips : https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_art_engine